# How can remove undefined style property value from inline tag element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have string `<p style="color: undefined; background: undefined; font-size: 12pt; text-align: undefined;">text-017</p>`  I want remove extra undefined style property from style attribute. The Tag element might div span etc. The output should  like this

```
<p style="font-size: 12pt;">text-017</p>
```

Please help us.

Thanks

Comment: Why not fix the actual problem where it adds such values?

Comment: These undefined values are coming from tinymce editor

Answer (score 2):

```js
let tempStr = 'p style="color: undefined; background: undefined; font-size: 12pt; text-align: undefined;">text-017</p>';
let undefinedStripped = tempStr.replace(/(.*style="|">.*)/g, '')    //get only the content in style attribute.
                               .split("; ")    //split each property with its value;
                               .filter(style => !style.includes("undefined"));    //stripe out all the properties with undefined value
//get all that except the string to be replaced and join it with the modified string.
const startStr = tempStr.match(/(.*style=")/g)[0];
const endStr = tempStr.match(/">.*/g)[0];
    
console.log(`${startStr}${undefinedStripped.join("")}${endStr}`);
```

Comment: Could you add some comment explanation to how this works each step

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = '<p style="color: undefined; background: undefined; font-size: 12pt; text-align: undefined">text-017</p>';
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = html;
var targetHTML = elem.firstChild;
var styleProps = targetHTML.getAttribute('style').split(';');
var newStyleProps = [];
styleProps.forEach(prop => {
    if (prop && !prop.includes('undefined')) {
        newStyleProps.push(prop.trim() + ';');
    }
});

var newStyle = newStyleProps.join(' ');
targetHTML.setAttribute('style', newStyle);
console.log(targetHTML)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Reset the element's attribute ang only run the 'font-size'.

```
$('p').attr('style', 'font-size:12pt');
```

Comment: These styles are dynamic not static